# Out of sample log-likelihood and accuracy for mirt item response theory models

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I'm trying to compute out of sample accuracy and log-likelihood of fitted IRT models (that is, predictive accuracy and log-likelihood for data not used to fit the model). I'm using the `fscores()` function to get score estimates, and then `probtrace()` with the estimated factor scores to get probabilities for accuracy and log-likelihood computation.

I am having some issues of 2-factor multidimensional models performing much worse than expected. I am not sure if there is something wrong with my thinking, if I'm using the package in the wrong way or if there is an issue with the package?

Below is a working example with the LSAT7 data for which I'm using the training data to test my own log-likelihood computation. Why is my log-likelihood for the 2 factor model so much larger than the one retrieved from mirt using `logLik()`?

```r
library(mirt)

data <- expand.table(LSAT7)
itemstats(data)

mod1 <- mirt(data, 1)
mod2 <- mirt(data, 2)

mirt_measures <- function(dat, mod, start0 = FALSE, inverse_coded = FALSE) {
  thetas <- fscores(mod, response.pattern = dat)
  probs <- get_mirt_probs(thetas[, grepl("^F", colnames(thetas))], mod)
  log_lik <- acc <- 0
  for (item in seq_along(probs)) {
    if (inverse_coded) { # multidimensional model has revers relationship between prob and score
      dat[, item] <- max(dat[, item]) - dat[, item]
    }
    for (person_id in seq_len(nrow(dat))) {
      if (!is.na(dat[person_id, item])) {
        score_ind <- dat[person_id, item] + 1
        log_lik <- log_lik + log(probs[[item]][person_id, score_ind])
        acc <- acc + (which.max(probs[[item]][person_id, ]) == score_ind)
      }
    }
  }
  acc = acc / (nrow(dat) * length(probs))
  return(c("ll" = log_lik, "acc" = acc))
}

get_mirt_probs <- function(theta, mod) {
  probs <- list()
  for (item in 1:extract.mirt(mod, "nitems")) {
    extr <- extract.item(mod, item)
    probs[[item]] <- probtrace(extr, theta)
  }
  probs
}

logLik(mod1)
logLik(mod2)
mirt_measures(data, mod1)
mirt_measures(data, mod2)
```